# Do you know why the partition leader is " - 1 " and how to solve it?

Tags: apache-kafka

i have tried to stop all brokers belonging to the same ISR for testing.

All producer was sending exactly partition 0. When the broker 11 and 12 shut down, consumer could no longer receive the message. And leader got - 1.

The partition did not function normally until came back the corresponding leader.

Do you know what is the solution? And why?

[image]

When all ISR brokers are stopped.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. However, if you favor availability over consistency you can enable unclean leader election (see docs: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs). This is not recommended unless you are sure you want availability at the cost of message loss.

> unclean.leader.election.enable
>
> Indicates whether to enable replicas not in the ISR set to be elected as leader as a last resort, even though doing so may result in data loss

Answer (score 0):

If the broker in ISR are down, then that partition goes offline.This is how the framework works , please read the kafka documentation for more details.